# Expo with react-native-share

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-share

On an expo react native project:
I'm trying to share multiple files through my expo app. I can currently share one file with expo-sharing.
Has anyone had any success with the react-native-share package on expo? I found this link where it seems some people have figured it out, but I'm not planning on ejecting from expo:
https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-for-react-native-share

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expo-dev-client](https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/) without the need to eject.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [expo-sharing](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/), for me is the only library that works for share.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35742043)